# Adjectives in -ья, -ье

Tags: прилагательные

I was doubtful when I saw the words **коровье молоко** and **козье молоко**. Then I checked an electronic dictionary (*Толковый словарь русского языка* for Mac), and there **-ья/-ье** where referred as the replacements for **-ий** in their respective adjectives.

So far I knew that there are, in Russian, *hard adjectives* (красив.ый, -ая, -ое, -ые), *soft adjectives* (соседн.ий, -яя, -ее, -ие) and *mixed adjectives* resulting from the spelling requirements after some consonants (хорош.ий, -ая, -ее, -ие).

Is **ья/ье** an irregular soft ending? Does it decline just like the regular soft endings (in which *feminine genitive* is **-ей** and *neuter genitive* is **-его**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at this from another angle. It is not irregular ending, but irregular stem - a soft sign is attached to it in most forms. It also replaces a vowel in the ending if it is duplicated (**-яя**, **-ии**, **-ее**, **-юю**).

So you have

средн**ий** - коров**ий**

средн**его** - коровь**его**

etc., but

средн**яя** - коровь**я**

средн**юю** - коровь**ю**

etc.

There is an exception from this rule in nominative/accusative plural:

средн**ие** but коровь**и**

Comment: I see. So those possessive adjectives decline almost the same way as common soft adjectives, with the distinction that the letter ь appears in all oblique cases, and feminine accusative is ью instead of юю. If it were not for your example with коровий, I would think that -ий/-ье/-ья would be replaced by -его/-его/-ей rather than -ьего/-ьего/-ьей! 
And how does plural decline in that case? Is nominative коровие? Its respective genitive turns into коровьих?

Comment: @swutra Ah, that is the exception I didn't notice. In plural nominative/accusative it shall be коровь**и**.

Comment: The key irregularity here, I think, is lack of the **-н-** suffix which is otherwise common in adjectives derived from nouns.

Answer (score 1):

Such adjectives are called *притяжательные прилагательные*, *posessive adjectives*. The ending ий-ье-ья is  common for "animal" posessive adjectives. We can see two types of their declension:

```
корова - коровий - коровье
коза - козий - козье
овца - овечий - овечье
кошка - кошачий - кошачьe
обезьяна - обезьяний - обезьянье
птица - птичий - птичье
рыба - рыбий - рыбье
верблюд - верблюжий - верблюжье
слон - слоновий - слоновье
волк - волчий - волчье
заяц - заячий - заячье
лис/лиса - лисий - лисье
дельфин - дельфиний - дельфинье
крокодил - крокодилий - крокодилье

зверь - звериный - звериное    
оса - осиный - осиное
пчела - пчелиный - пчелиное
муравей - муравьиный - муравьиное
кура/курица - куриный - куриное
змея - змеиный - змеиное
```

Some declense both ways. For example, there are both `соколиный` and `соколий`, both `стрекозиный` and `стрекозий`.